# Comment traduire « (the whole) fracas » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, adjectifs

> — They canceled the All Valley [tournament].[...]
>  City council
> just pulled the permit. Something about not wanting to foster a
> culture of violence after the [whole](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/whole) [fracas](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/fracas) at the school.
> It's an over-correction, if you ask me.
>
> Ron, dans *Cobra Kai* (Westbrook/Sony), S03E08, 8:00...

Le contexte de cette fiction c'est les arts martiaux et la formation de clans et une confrontation de leur membres à l'école où il y eu des blessés etc.

Comment traduire le *(whole) fracas* (« a noisy argument or fight », *Merriam Learners*) et comment motive-t-on son choix plutôt qu'un autre ; par exemple choisit-on de traduire l'adjectif et est-ce que ça nous amènerait à changer de registre et pourquoi est-ce que ce serait une traduction fidèle ou non ?

Comment: Une agitation fracassante (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fracassant)

Answer (score 1):

Quelques suggestions: zizanie, bordel, foutoir, tohu-bohu.

Comment: Vas-tu tous les faire précéder de _tout(e) ce(tte)_ dans la phrase et _bordel_ et _foutoir_ sont-ils du même registre que les deux autres, et eux sont-ils du même style que le reste du lexique dans la phrase ?

Comment: Je suppose que "whole fracas" doit mieux coller avec *zizanie* ou *tohu-bohu* alors que *bordel* et *foutoir*, comme tu dois t'en douter, sont d'un registre moins soutenu.